# How to loop through all the elements returned from getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, getelementsbytagname

I am trying to loop through all the elements retruned from `getElementsByTagName("input")` using forEach. Any ideas why this does not work in FF, Chrome or IE?

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <script>
            function ShowResults(value, index, ar) {
                alert(index);
            }
            var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            alert(input.length);
            input.forEach(ShowResults);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rationale why no `forEach`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433799/why-doesnt-nodelist-have-foreach

Comment: Now in ES6 NodeList has `forEach`, but HTMLCollection still doesn't. Unfortunately, `getElementsByTagName` returns HTMLCollection. Consider using `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Is there an error message?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You need to convert the nodelist to array with this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <input type="text" value="" />
        <script>
            function ShowResults(value, index, ar) {
                alert(index);
            }
            var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var inputList = Array.prototype.slice.call(input);
            alert(inputList.length);
            inputList.forEach(ShowResults);
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

or use for loop.

```
for(let i = 0;i < input.length; i++)
{
    ShowResults(input[i].value);
}
```

and change ShowResults function to:

```
function ShowResults(value) {
   alert(value);
}
```

**Why do we need to do that?**
Some objects in JavaScript look like an array, but they aren’t one. That usually means that they have indexed access and a length property, but none of the array methods. Examples include the special variable arguments, DOM node lists, and strings. Array-Like Objects and Generic Methods gives tips for working with array-like objects.
[source](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch18.html#_pitfall_array_like_objects)

**UPDATE for 07.10.2019** 
Nowdays with ES6 you can use `[...inputList].forEach`, or `Array.from(inputList)`

Comment: I was trying to use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff679980%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Comment: I have > 1000 hidden input fields on the form. Which option would be the most efficient in this case?

Comment: They both identical. Fell free to use whatever you want.

Comment: For `Array.prototype.slice.call(input)` you can use the shorthand `[].slice.call(input)`.

Comment: @Dvir the slice thing is a really cool trick. Can you explain the inner working of it?
EDIT: Got it in the documentation..cheers!

Comment: @YatinGera Read about the Array-like Objects in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Comment: I think you forgot the `let i` in the for loop.

Comment: @AgustinBarrachina if at the time the `let` was exists in JS it was amazing :)

Answer (score 73):

Yay, ES6:

```
const children = [...parent.getElementsByTagName('tag')];
children.forEach((child) => { /* Do something; */ });
```

[MDN Doc for Spread Operator (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)

Comment: Now in ES6 you can use `forEach` for NodeList, but not for HTMLCollection. `getElementsByTagName` returns HTMLCollection, whereas `querySelectorAll` returns NodeList.

Answer (score 33):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, which do not have a `forEach` method. But, there's a simple tweak that will allow you to iterate with `forEach` *without* creating an intermediate array: use `querySelectorAll` instead. `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, and modern browsers have a `NodeList.prototype.forEach` method:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input')
  .forEach((input) => {
    console.log(input.value);
  });
```

```html
<input type="text" value="foo">
<input type="text" value="bar">
```

Another benefit to using `querySelectorAll` is that it accepts comma-separated *CSS selectors*, which are far more flexible and precise than just tag names. For example, the selector

```
.container1 > span, .container2 > span
```

will only match `span`s which are children of elements with a class of `container1` or `container2`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.container1 > span, .container2 > span')
  .forEach((span) => {
    span.classList.add('highlight');
  });
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>bar</span>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <span>baz</span>
</div>
<div class="container3">
  <span>buzz</span>
</div>
```

If you want to use `NodeList.prototype.forEach` on ancient browsers that do not have the method built-in, simply add a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Polyfill). The following snippet will work on IE11:

```js
// Polyfill:
if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
  NodeList.prototype.forEach = function(callback, thisArg) {
    thisArg = thisArg || window;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      callback.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this);
    }
  };
}

// Main code:
document.querySelectorAll('.container1 > span, .container2 > span')
  .forEach(function(span) {
    span.classList.add('highlight');
  });
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <span>foo</span>
  <span>bar</span>
</div>
<div class="container2">
  <span>baz</span>
</div>
<div class="container3">
  <span>buzz</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Because `input` is not an array, it's [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)
Use a `for` loop would be better.

And since `HTMLCollection`s are array-like objects you can [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) `Array#forEach` on it like this

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(input, ShowResults);
```

Answer (score 9):

The reason, this does not work is because '**getElementsByTagName**' returns an array - like Object rather than an actual array. In case you are not aware, here's how both of them look like :-

```
var realArray = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var arrayLike = {
  0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'c',
  length: 3
};
```

Thus, since Array-like objects inherit from '**Object.prototype**' instead of '**Array.prototype**', this means that Array-like Objects can't access common Array prototype methods like forEach(), push(), map(), filter(), and slice().

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is a very well explanation

Answer (score 6):

It's becauseinput is html collection. html collection don't have forEach.

you can easily conver it to array by Array.prototype.slice

example:

```
function ShowResults(value, index, ar) {
            alert(index);
        }
        var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        alert(input.length);
input = Array.prototype.slice.call(input)
        input.forEach(ShowResults);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fPuKt/1/

Answer (score 6):

If you can use ES2015, you can use `Array.from()` to convert the `HTMLCollection` returned by `getElementsByTagName()` into a real array. If you change line 11 to the following, the rest of the code works as-is:

```
var input = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("input"));
```

Answer (score 5):

In ES6 you can use the `spread` operator to convert an HtmlCollection to an Array. see this question [Why can't I use Array.forEach on a collection of Javascript elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797101/why-cant-i-use-array-foreach-on-a-collection-of-javascript-elements?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
input = [...input]
input.forEach(ShowResults)
```

Answer (score 3):

HTMLCollections doesn't have the same methods as arrays. You can check this thing by tiping this in the javascript console of your browser.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('some-class');
'forEach' in elements;
```

And the console will return `true` if `elements` (in this case) has a method called `forEach` to call.

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

```
HTMLCollection.prototype.map = Array.prototype.map;
```

You can now use map on every `HTMLCollection`.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input").map(
    input => console.log(input)
);
```

Comment: neat solution, thanks