# Javascript: match using dom loaded page

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to grab all links from google search result using `Chrome console`.

First I wanted to get the dom loaded source. I tried below code.

```
var source = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Now when I type `source` in console source it shows the correct dom loaded source. But if I run `alert(source);` It's showing default html source of page.

So problem is when I run below code

```
source.match(/class="r"><a href="(.*?)"/);
```

It is returning null, because variable `source` has the source code before dom loaded.

Comment: **Regex should not be enclosed in quotes**

Comment: @Tushar : edited , but still its not using the dom loaded source..using the html source

Comment: Is using a regex a must?

Comment: @miensol :  no , I am just need to get all link with class="r"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DOM API (i.e. [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)) to find all [`a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) tags in a page. Take a look:

```js
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
var matchingHrefs = Array.prototype.slice.call(anchors).filter(function(a) {
  return a.className == 'r';
}).map(function(a) {
  return a.href;
});
```

```html
<a href="#first" class="r">A</a>
<a href="#second" class="d">B</a>
<a href="#third" class="r">C</a>
```

The `Array.prototype.slice.call` call turns [node list into regular array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324700/javascript-loop-through-all-the-elements-returned-from-getelementsbytagname).

Comment: @Vishnu if the above doesn't suite your need please clarify your question. The link in your comment shows that you've run the code from answer - that's good - but it doesn't clarify at all what wrong still.

Comment: I am really really sorry , I guess its because page source contains <h3 class="r"><a href=" , I guess a alone doesnt contain any class..

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you need to add `/g` flag to your regex to match globally.

Like this:
`yourHtml.match(/href="([^"]*")/g)`

Comment: hey global seems to work , but when I use source.match(/class="r"><a href="(.*?)"/); , its returning full line istead of the required part...

Comment: @Vishnu seems like your regex is wrong. If you want to get all links with specified class I'd recommend you to use something like following `document.querySelectorAll('a[href][class="r"]')`. Its work just fine.

Comment: actually A is without any class, its like this  <h3 class="r"><a href="

Comment: @Vishnu then `document.querySelectorAll('h3.r a[href]')`.

Comment: thanks but its returning whole <a href="xxxxx">xxxxx</a>

Comment: @Vishnu `var yourLinks = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.r a[href]')).map(function(aEl) { return aEl.href });`