# forEach works on querySelectorAll, but not getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, getelementsbytagname, selectors-api

While coding something, I came across something pretty weird.

The following code works just fine:

```
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(e);
    });
});
```

However, the following does not:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("button").forEach(function(e) {
    e.addEventListener("click", function() {
        console.log(e);
    });
})
```

I'm very confused here. As far as I can tell, `document.getElementsByTagName("button")` returns the exact same array as `document.querySelectorAll("button")`. Am I wrong? What is the problem here? Is it related to `forEach`?

**side notes:**

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324700/javascript-loop-through-all-the-elements-returned-from-getelementsbytagname) but it doesn't answer my question.

just emphasizing: I'm not using jQuery.

P.S. - I am already aware of the differences and pros and cons between `forEach` vs a regular `for` loop, so unless `forEach` is specifically the reason these two functions are not working the same way, the `forEach` vs `for` debate is unrelated to my question.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbilo.png

Comment: getElementsByTagName returns a HTMLCollection - querySelectorAll returns a NodeList - NodeList has (in some browsers) a forEach method - [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility)

Comment: if you want to use document.getElementsByTagName("button") you can do like this Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("button")).forEach();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is in whats returned from those methods. `querySelectorAll` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) while `getElementsByTagName` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). None of them support the generic [Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) but NodeList implements its own [NodeList.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) which is what you are hitting here.