# connect an event to all the html elements of a certain tag or a certain class

Tags: javascript

(with pure javascript) how I can connect an event to all the elements of a certain tag or a certain class?
Using "querySelector", they select only one item (the first), while using "getElementByTagName" or "getElementByClassName" not I select none (I display an error in the console).

Thanks so much.

```js
//byCssSelector - CLASS
document.querySelector(".myClass").addEventListener("click", function() { alert("ok"); });
// byCssSelector - TAG
document.querySelector("section").addEventListener("click", function() { alert("ok"); });

//byClass
document.getElementByClassName("myClass2").addEventListener("click", function() { alert("ok"); });
//byTag
document.getElementByTagName("div").addEventListener("click", function() { alert("ok"); });
```

```html
<br><b>querySelector:</b><br>
<p class="myClass">1) querySelector(".class")</p>
<section>2) querySelector("[tag]")</section>
<br><b>Tag/Class-name:</b><br>
<span class="myClass2">3) getElementByTagName</span>
<div>4) getElementByClassName</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelector` only returns the first element it finds. You should user `querySelectorAll`, which returns a list of elements matching the tag. You can then user `forEach`, to loop through the elements and attach a listener to every one of them.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.myClass').forEach(function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert('ok');
  });
});
```

`NodeList.forEach` is a new feature and is not supported in all browsers. You can check compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility). If you wish to support them, you will have to use `for` loop or convert `nodeList`  to `array`.

You can use `[].slice.call` for it. If you are using `ES6/ES2015`, you can even look into `Array.from`

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: @Rajesh yes. Why?

Comment: NodeList does not have `.forEach` function

Comment: It actually does - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: Its recently added. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

> while using "getElementByTagName" or "getElementByClassName" not I
>   select none (I display an error in the console).

There are 2 mistakes

- It should be **getElementsByTagName**, not **getElementByTagName**
- **getElementsByTagName** returns a live collection of nodes, not a single element.

Make it

```
var x = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementByClassName("myClass2"));
x.forEach( function(el){
  el.addEventListener("click", function() { alert("ok"); });
});
```

Comment: Ops, thanks, I had not noticed

Answer (score 0):

`.querySelector`, as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector),

> Returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified group of selectors.

```js
var divs = document.querySelector('.content');
console.log(divs)
```

```html
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
<div class="content">4</div>
```

Where as what you are looking for is [.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.content');
console.log(divs)
```

```html
<div class="content">1</div>
<div class="content">2</div>
<div class="content">3</div>
<div class="content">4</div>
```

Once you have the list, you can refer following link to [loop over nodeList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324700/javascript-loop-through-all-the-elements-returned-from-getelementsbytagname)

A useful reference: [querySelector and querySelectorAll vs getElementsByClassName and getElementById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377590/queryselector-and-queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbyclassname-and-getelementbyid)

Comment: This should have been a comment

Comment: So, the answer to his question should be a comment? Just because his problem is really easy to fix doesn't make it necessary to be a comment.

Comment: First its an obvious duplicate and I'll be marking it as one. You do not have enough rep as of now, but please when you have, mark questions as duplicate instead of answering them. Secondly, this is not an answer. Answer has explanation of what is wrong or what can be improved with code samples and possible reference links. Basically, if someone a year later reads this answer, he/she should learn something from it.

Comment: I follow what you're saying and can agree with it partially (about the duplicate part), but I am pointing out what his mistake is and how it can be improved, am I not?

Comment: I have updated your answer. Please check if it conveys the same message. If not, please revert it.

Comment: Of course adding more information and references only makes the answer better. It's only up to you how wide you're making your answer... You could write a book as an answer, but would that help more than just the few rules that help him out with his question? I would know what to choose...