# Where to get documentation on NodeList object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

I tried to run this command in console on some page

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*").filter(function(element) {return element.scrollTop && element.scrollTop>0})
```

and got an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).filter is not a function
```

The returned value is of type `NodeList`, which apparently ["is not an array"](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodelist.asp). That's cool, but what is it?

**UPDATE**

The following line

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*").forEach(function(element) {if( element.scrollTop && element.scrollTop>0) console.log(element);});
```

also causes the same error, so `getElementsByTagName()` function doesn't return something, containing `forEach()` method.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList

Comment: Why `mozilla`? Is this true for all browsers?

Comment: @Dims If you refer the end of page, you will see the [specifications](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist). Also, MDN is a very descriptive portal to get understand any concept. They have syntax, basic example and list of available and deprecated function and more importantly, they also have browser compatibility and specification list

Comment: @Rajesh but is says `NodeList` has `forEach` method, which is not true https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Comment: "The returned value is of type NodeList" — It isn't. `getElementsByTagName` returns a "live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)", not a NodeList.

Comment: @Quentin how would I knew this?

Comment: @Dims — By reading the documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Comment: @Dims Please refer [Browser Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility) as well. This is a new feature only available in modern browsers

Comment: I'm confused. The first Google result for `getElementsByTagName` points to the MDN page.

Comment: @torazaburo for me it returns https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/met_document_getelementsbytagname.asp which says it returns NodeList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Who's responsible for maintaining documentation on these classes?

The Worldwide Web Consortium. See https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#old-style-collections:-nodelist-and-htmlcollection.

As others have mentioned, MDN is a usually-reliable source of good documentation as well.

There's also plenty of information right here on SO. For instance, a search for "stack overflow getelementsbytagname foreach" turned up this right away: [JavaScript: Loop through all the elements returned from getElementsByTagName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324700/javascript-loop-through-all-the-elements-returned-from-getelementsbytagname).