# Find input elements but only those which have onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbytagname

Some of my input elements have onclick="setSomeFunction()" which displays or hides the following few div(s).

I can find the input elements via
document.getElementsByTagName("input")
and put those in an array.
But I want to get only the "onclick" inputs into another array.

I have found that you can test for .class, (for example)

```
if (document.getElementById("someId").class == "block" )
```

but it seems that if there is no corresponding ".onclick"? Or does my code fail because some input element doesn't have an onclick event at all?

```
function consoleInputs() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); //finds all the input elements
    console.log(inputs); //list all the inputs
    var hasClick; // store all the inputs WITH onclick event here
    var loop = inputs.length; // max rounds in the loop
    var i;
    for (i = 0;i <= loop ;i += 1){
        if ((document.getElementById("inputs[i]").onclick) == ("set"+"*")) {
        hasClick = hasClick + inputs[i]
        }
    }
    console.log(hasClick);
}
```

I've tried different if statements, but no luck, really... I keep getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onclick' of null

I haven't learned enough about jQuery yet, so please avoid.

Comment: That is saying you have `id="inputs[i]"` not `id="inputs0"`

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand...

Is not inputs[i] the way to find the element id from the inputs array?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript has selector feature that is pretty much similar to jQuery's one.

So you could get all inputs that have onClick attribute by

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[onClick]')
```

which will return you array of input elements that have onClick attribute defined.

### Edit

CSS have startsWith selector as well, so you can get onclick attributes that starts with `set` with this

`document.querySelectorAll('input[onClick^="set"]')`

Comment: [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) will return a [nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Check this if you want to convert it to an array : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324700/javascript-loop-through-all-the-elements-returned-from-getelementsbytagname

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('input[onClick]') 
did help, thank you!

I also tried converting nodelist to array, but I'm not sure I got that right.

Comment: Is it possible to also find only the onclick events that start with "set", such as the  onclick="setSomeFunction()" mentions in the opening post?

Comment: Oh super! I tried using "~=" for "contains" but there seems to be so many different operators in different circumstances and I couldn't find it!