# Iterate over elements in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, puppeteer

I have a webpage, where I want to hover over all anchor tags and get the styles computed for that tag. This function which I wrote doesn't seem to work as it gives me original style of the anchor and not the hover styles.
Please help.

```
let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    properties = []
    for (var element of elements){
        element.focus();
        properties.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window.getComputedStyle(element, null)["backgroundColor"])));
    }
    return properties;
});
```

Comment: Try `Array.from(..., (element) => (document.getComputedStyle(element, null)["backgroundColor"])`

Comment: Please elaborate.

Comment: This approach won't work, you need first to add a listener to each element first and then call focus of each `element. inputValue[i].addEventListener('focus', yourListenerHere, false);` then you call `element.focus()`

Comment: How to add listener?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle
try document.getComputedStyle(element, ':hover')

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should [convert results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41195514/3708596) from `document.getElementsByTagName` to normal array

```
const elements = [...document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')];
```

Next to get element property use this syntax:

```
window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("background-color")
```

Finally, this is a fully working example:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus/');


  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const elements = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea');

    return [...elements].map(element => {
      element.focus();
      return window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("background-color");
    });
  });

  console.log(data);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) to obtain an [`ElementHandle`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle) array of `textarea` elements.

Then, you can use the [`elementHandle.hover()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandlehover) to hover over each element and then [`page.evaluate()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to obtain the computed background color to push to your `data` array:

```
const elements = await page.$$( 'textarea' );
const data = [];

for ( let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++ )
{
    await elements[i].hover();

    data.push( await page.evaluate( element => window.getComputedStyle( element ).backgroundColor, elements[i] ) );
}

console.log( data );
```