# how can i console the list of DOM object with javascript

Tags: javascript, console

when i get an element with jQuery and console.log() the element i can see all methods that i can do something with.
but when i use javascript to show element in console it just show the element itself instead of show me methods like _.style _.accessKey and so on, like when i do $(this)[0] with jQuery.
so how to see all these methods in pure javascript ?

Comment: a console log in most browsers wil show you the whole object including its methods and properties. Else you can write your own traversal function and print them out using console.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following:-

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];

console.table(div) or console.dir(div)
```

This will print out all the properties available in a neat table format.

Comment: tnks a lot. but is there any way that i can show them like an object ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324700/javascript-loop-through-all-the-elements-returned-from-getelementsbytagname

Comment: @abhidev this answer is fine. i just need the IMG object not the table.
can you help me with this ? :-)

Comment: console.dir(div) is exactly what i want. tnks to all.

Comment: Oh yes, you can use that if you need an object. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

use console.dir() to see all the methods for javascript DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following ways to find html elements:

```
var x = document.getElementById('id');
console.log(x);

var y = document.getElementsByTagName('tag_name');
console.log(y);

var z = document.getElementsByClassName('class_name');
console.log(z);
```

and then list all methods and properties associated with that element by creating one new object and then call the function

```
function getAllMethods(object) {
       return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object).filter(function(property) {
        return typeof object[property] == 'function';
}

console.log(getAllMethods("object"));
```