# gets an error when using forEach on a collection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

the following code returns an array of 3 dialog elements, but when I try .forEach I get an error saying

> document.getElementsByTagName(...).forEach is not a function

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("dialog").forEach(elm => {
    elm.removeAttr("open");
});
```

Comment: Which browser/version are you running?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl firefox developer 87.0b7

Comment: Here is your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54191445/1762224). The `getElementsByTagName` function returns an `HTMLCollection`. If you use `querySelectorAll` instead, it will return a `NodeList`. The latter result will have the `forEach` method. Note, you can convert the `HTMLCollection` to an array-like structure by spreading it. `[...document.getElementsByTagName("dialog")].forEach...` But just use the following instead: `document.querySelectorAll("dialog").forEach...`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl jupp works great!