# How can i create an HTML tag through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small menu of 5 items here. What I am trying to do is if the "lollipops" option is selected and a user clicks add to cart button, JavaScript should create a new

tag. I am new to JavaScript and would appreciate any directions or suggestions about what I am doing wrong. I posted a copy of my HTML and JavaScript code below, so please take a look thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Assignment 2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="material">

                <label for="items">Choose an Item: </label>
                <select id="items">
                    <option id="lollipops">Box of Lollipops - $2.00</option>
                    <option id="recipes">Book of Recipes - $4.99</option>
                    <option id="giftwrap">Gift wrapper - $2.75</option>
                    <option id="dogTreats">Dog Treats - $5.00</option>
                    <option id="catTreats">Cat Treats - $$5.00</option>
                </select>

                <input type="button" value="Add To Cart" id="addToCart" onclick="addToCart()">

                <div id="cart">


                    <p id="beforeTax">Before Tax: </p>
                    <p id="price">Total: </p>
                </div>

                <br>

                <label for="name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
                
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
                
                <br><br><br>
                
                <label for="creditCard">Credit card number</label>
                <input type="text" id="creditCard" placeholder="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx">
                
                <label for="expiryDate">Expiry Date: </label>
                <input type="month">

                <br><br><br>

            </div>    
        </div>

        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
//let lollipopsPrice = document.getElementById("lollipops").value;
//let recipePrice= document.getElementById("recipes").value;
//let giftwrapPrice = document.getElementById("giftwrap").value;
//let dogTreatsPrice = document.getElementById("dogsTreats").value;
//let catTreatsPrice = document.getElementById("catTreats").value;

function addToCart()
{

    let item=document.getElementsByTagName("option").value;

    if (item.value=="Box of Lollipops - $2.00")
    {
        document.write("<p>Box of Lollipops - $2.00</p>");
    }


    console.log();

}
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns an HTMLCollection which is an array-like, so you can't access the `value` directly on it, but will need to iterate over the returned collection.

Comment: also: [How to loop through all the elements returned from getElementsByTagName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324700/how-to-loop-through-all-the-elements-returned-from-getelementsbytagname)

Answer (score 0):

To write something in the document you can use can use [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append), or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

When the option is selected it will fire the `addToCart` function, and depending on where you want to write the new element (when you say "javascript should create a new tag", I imagine you mean a new element).

As you can see following the links, you create a div,p and text inside the p, like this:

```js
let div = document.createElement("div");
let p = document.createElement("p");
div.append(p)
p.append("some text")
```

or you could use innerHTML like this:

```js
p.innerHTML = "some text in innerHTML"
```

Even though, as stated on the Developer Mozilla site, `innerHTML` presents some vulnerability issues and it is recommended to use the [`setHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setHTML) method to sanitize user inputs. In your case it's a selection so it is not much relevant.