# Using forEach on an array from getElementsByClassName results in “TypeError: undefined is not a function”

Tags: javascript, foreach

In [my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jer2/zcrh9/3/), I’m simply trying to iterate over an array of elements. The array is non-empty, as the log statements prove. Yet the call to `forEach` gives me the (not so helpful) “Uncaught `TypeError`: `undefined` is not a function” error.

I must be doing something stupid; what am I doing wrong?

My code:

```js
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]);
arr.forEach(function(v, i, a) {
  console.log(v);
});
```

```css
.myClass {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">Hello</div>
```

Comment: `arr` is not an array, but a `HTMLCollection`. It doesn't have the same methods as an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName . Here's a SO post about it even: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433799/why-doesnt-nodelist-have-foreach

Comment: Something like `[1,2,3].forEach(function(v,i,a) {
    console.log(v);
});` is fine.  What's the difference between this and the array in my example?

Comment: You **don't** have an **array** in your example. What makes you think it's an array?

Comment: @Ian - the fact that I used getElementsByClassName elsewhere and iterated over it using a regular for loop.  You learn something new every day!

Comment: Ahh that's what I expected you to say. So yeah, as dystroy pointed out in his answer, there are array-like objects that can "act" the same way - having indexes for properties...which is what `getElementsByClassName` returns

Comment: @Jer: As `arr instanceof Array` will result in `false` it cannot avail of any prototype methods of the `Array` object such as [**Array.prototype.forEach()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). `arr` is a [**HTMLCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection#Usage_in_JavaScript) and an array like object (but does not inherit from or instantiate `Array`). Hence your standard `for` loop will work as that simply iterates through index of the object and is not a prototype of `Array`.

Comment: @Jer—you should look into the differences between built–in and host objects. The former conform to ECMA-262, the later only as much as the host wishes. The DOM has many objects that allow access to members by index (document.images, document.forms, form.elements, select.options, etc.), mostly based on the [*NodeList* interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177).

Answer (score 180, accepted):

That's because  `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not an array.

Fortunately it's an ["array-like" object](https://www.inkling.com/read/javascript-definitive-guide-david-flanagan-6th/chapter-7/array-like-objects) (which explains why it's logged as if it was an object and why you can iterate with a standard `for` loop), so you can do this :

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName('myClass'), function(v,i,a) {
```

With ES6 (on modern browsers or with Babel), you may also use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) which builds arrays from array-like objects:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')).forEach(v=>{
```

or spread the array-like object into an array:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('myClass'))].forEach(v=>{
```

Comment: I'm glad I posted, I never would have considered this!  Are there other JavaScript data structures that can be accessed like `foo[0]` but are not arrays?

Comment: @Jer `arguments` is one. jQuery objects are another. You could make one yourself: `var a = {"0": "str1", "1": "str2", length: 2}`

Comment: Here we go with old browsers again… passing a host object to a native method will fail in IE 8 and lower. Maybe no one cares, but some might. ;-) Oh, it doesn't support *getElementsByClassName* either, but `querySelectorAll('.myClass')` should work. I'm still waiting for iterators to be added to the NodeList API. :-(

Comment: @Ian Normally you also need the splice function.

Comment: @Jer: As a side-note if you intend to break out of the loop for any reason `Array.prototype.forEach` won't let you do that. If you have that requirement later use standard `for` loop or if you want to use the array object use `Array.prototype.every` or `Array.prototype.some` (note though that every/some are not supported in IE8 or less)

Comment: @dystroy You mean `slice`?

Comment: @Ian No. [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), which is the function you used to change the array.

Comment: @dystroy Right, but I guess I'm wondering what you meant by "you also need the splice function" - for what? As an example, I would usually use `slice` to "copy" `arguments` into an array, but I've never had a need for `splice`

Comment: @Ian You need splice for the object to be "array-like". Compare the logs here : http://jsbin.com/sigut/1/edit

Comment: @dystroy Ooooooh! I had no idea what you meant until you posted that. I see now :) I always took "array-like" to just need indexes and a `length` property. But I also just read your "array-like" article you included in your answer and it mentions the inclusion of important `Array.prototype`, so I'd include more than `splice`, but still, I see your point of needing to modify the structure

Comment: @Ian TBH the definition of "array-like" is very fuzzy and depends on the use. Sometimes I doesn't include `splice` in that definition but when I want to be more "array-like" to be able to use `map`, `filter`, and so on, then I include it. Simple iteration using `forEach` doesn't need `splice`.

Comment: @dystroy You're definitely right that it's fuzzy. I guess my example was for the ability to access items (like you said, you don't need `splice` for that, especially with `forEach`), but definitely adding methods like `map` and `filter` help when you need them!

Answer (score 11):

Try this it should work :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="myClass">Hello</div>
   <div class="myClass">Hello</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
    console.log(arr);
    console.log(arr[0]);
    arr = [].slice.call(arr); //I have converted the HTML Collection an array
    arr.forEach(function(v,i,a) {
        console.log(v);
    });
</script>


<style type="text/css">
    .myClass {
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
</style>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the event that you want to access the ID of each element of a specific class you can do the following:

```
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')).forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element.id);
    });
```