# How can I add a link around every image on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, anchor, dom-traversal

I want to add a link to all images on the page. The link should point to the image source.

For example, from this:

```
<img src="foo.jpg">
```

I want to get this:

```
<a href="foo.jpg"><img src="foo.jpg"></a>
```

I tried to do it like the following but nothing seems to happen. Do I then have to somehow add the new "a" element somewhere?

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var image in images) {
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = image.src;
  a.innerHtml = image;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over the indices (0, 1, 2, ...) of `images` in this line:

```
for (var image in images) {
```

If `image` were an HTML element, this line still wouldn't work because the `innerHTML` property expects HTML text, not an object:

```
a.innerHtml = image;
```

Finally, you have neglected to add the anchor to the document.

Here is a correct way to do it:

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
  var img = images[i];
  var a = document.createElement('a');  // Make a new anchor.
  a.href = img.src;                     // Point it at the image source.
  img.parentNode.replaceChild(a, img);  // Replace the image with the anchor.
  a.appendChild(img);                   // Make the image a child of the anchor.
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcOyt.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPkNZ.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kd7GM.png">
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This works great, although I did it with forEach in the end. :-)

Comment: @user5721808 That's fine as long as you don't call `forEach` on the value returned by [`getElementsByTagName`, which is not an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266313/) and does not support `forEach` according to the JavaScript standard.

Answer (score 2):

You just create the `Tag`, but not insert it to the `Document`.
You can use `replaceChild` method in [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) to replace the `Img` tag.

Answer (score -1):

for each loops are somewhat strange in javascript, you need to access objects like this:

```
for (var image in images) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = images[image].src;
    a.innerHtml = images[image];
    a.appendChild(images[image]);
    // then of course you need to replace the img with the anchor containing the image 
    images[image].parentNode.replaceChild(a, images[image]);
}
```

Generally speaking:

```
for(var obj in list) {
    var current = list[obj];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to not work either. From adding `console.log(image)` it does seem that you are correct that this syntax should be used, but still the HTML is not changed to wrap the img tags in a tags.

Comment: Do you even append the new link child? You need to `containerElement.appendChild(a);`

Comment: @NiklasVest I didn't downvote your answer, but I see the problem. You haven't wrapped each image in an anchor, which is what the question is asking for.

Comment: @Michael Laszlo Indeed thanks! whenever i read a question i know i can answer i get overly excited and leave out reading the other half of the question!

Answer (score -1):

May I suggest `jQuery`?

The following example won't work in the sandbox because of browser restrictions, but should work on a site that you control. Also, depending on circumstances, the browser might block the popup. But, in the case of links within the webpage own domain, this might be the better solution, because you avoid manipulating the DOM.

```js
$(function () {
  $('img').on('click', function () {
    var win = window.open($(this).attr('src'), '_blank')
    win.focus()
  })
})
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
```

Here is another approach, wrapping all the images in an `a` tag as you originally requested:

```js
$(function () {
  $('img').wrap(function () {
    return '<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '"></a>'  
  })
})
```

```css
img {
 border: 1px solid blue;
 cursor: pointer;
 float: left;
 margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
```

Comment: The, down vote button is not a "I hate jQuery" or "I don't like this" button. This is a valid solution and it works. Please explain your vote.

Comment: I'll have you know that i liked your solution and that i gave it an upvote :D

Comment: Thanks, I say a helpful answer is a good answer, but [on SO], only one answer can be the correct answer. Unless the answer is abusive, heavily misinforming, insecure or dangerous, there is no need to down-vote.

Comment: If there was a comperative or superlative of `true` i'd assign it to you statement right there.

Comment: In fact what I just wrote aligns with SO's [own guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Comment: You didn't even try to explain where OP went wrong with his/her code and just blindly suggest some bloated, unneeded library. Imo that is not useful.

Comment: "Not useful" is no grounds for a down vote. I still think this can be useful to some, and `jQuery` is in fact the right tool for this specific job. I imagine that someone who wants to do this kind of DOM manipulation post render, will be doing more of it elsewhere. I don't use `jQuery` myself anymore because I'm using `React.js`, but `jQuery` still made my life much easier for many years before. Did you read [this]?

Comment: "not useful" *is* grounds for a downvote. Hell even the downvote title tells you this: `<a class="vote-down-off vote-down-on" title="This answer is not useful (click again to undo)">down vote</a>`