# Select the value of <select> using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm getting all the option drop downs like so

```
var options = $(".options");
```

Then I try a simple jquery .val to select the second option

```
options[0].val("1")
```

And I get the following error

```
options[0].val is not a function
```

**Notes:**

```
console.log(options[0]); // returns <select>...</select>
```

**Update Edit**

https://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/pen/NaxyJK?editors=1010 Relevant code is near the bottom --> listsDropDown

Comment: Getting closer with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266313/using-foreach-on-an-array-from-getelementsbyclassname-results-in-typeerror-und

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/9tao32gm/

```js
$('select option[value="2"]').prop("selected", "selected");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

If you are using jQuery version < 1.6 then use `attr` instead of `prop`

```
$('select option[value="2"]').attr("selected", "selected");
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How does this work on an array of options? Where my variable options has more than one <select>? The problem is it's saying .val and .attr are not functions of option[0]

Comment: @TylerL Please share your `HTML` code, then only I can help you better.

Comment: Thank you so much @Shiladitya. https://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/pen/NaxyJK?editors=1010 // listDropDown

Answer (score 1):

There are different methods to set the selection of an option:

```
1. $("#select_id").get(0).selectedIndex=1;  
2. $("#select_id").val(4);   
3. $("#select_id option[text='jQuery']").attr("selected", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

$(".options") is document.getelementbyclassname which returns an HTML Collection instead of an array. To convert it to array, you use slice and call.

```
  var optionsArr = $(".options");
  optionsArr = [].slice.call(optionsArr);
  optionsArr.forEach(function (item, index){ 
    $('.selectList'+index+' option[value='+index+']').attr("selected", "selected");
  });
```

For more detail, see this answer [Using forEach on an array from getElementsByClassName results in “TypeError: undefined is not a function”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266313/using-foreach-on-an-array-from-getelementsbyclassname-results-in-typeerror-und)

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue in the question. Consider updating your answer to explain what this does and how it addresses the problem - this will help not just the OP but others with similar issues. Please review [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)