# JavaScript show / hide html elements

Tags: javascript

Is there a cleaner way of achieving this in JavaScript,
I'm trying to show / hide items based on a click function

```
var overview = document.getElementById("overview"); 
var schedule = document.getElementById("schedule");
var reports = document.getElementById("reports");

    function btnOverview_Click() {
        schedule.style.display = "none";
        reports.style.display = "none";
        overview.style.display = "block";
    }       
    function btnSchedule_Click() {
        overview.style.display = "none";
        reports.style.display = "none";
        schedule.style.display = "block";
    } 
    function btnReports_Click() {
        overview.style.display = "none";
        schedule.style.display = "none";
        reports.style.display = "block";
    }
```

Comment: Please, show some HTML markup - The way you're nesting your elements could be of help

Comment: "Is there a cleaner way of achieving this" if you just want to show/hide some elements then I'd say no. But if you have access to html and want to achive tab-like or accordion-like functionality then - yes. You could make code more generic using classes and data-attributes.

Comment: Do you want another way like not changing display property or want better code to do same thing

Comment: Better code to do the same thing - maybe I'm wrong but this seems like a very "bloated" solution. All the elements are at the same "level" - I don't want to access them by their selector - their position, id, class, could change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoiding all possible inline styling and JavaScript,
I suggest you to do the following:

```js
// I added a class in your HTML
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".myClass");
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".myButtons");

// Function to hide all "elements" except the one we clicked
function hideExceptThis() {
  elements.forEach(elm => elm.style.display = "none");
  // Get the value in "data" attribute
  var id = this.getAttribute("data"); // "this" refers to the one you clicked
  document.querySelector(id).style.display = "block";
}

// On load, bind the above function on click for each element
buttons.forEach(but => but.addEventListener("click", hideExceptThis));
```

```css
#panel {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 8px;
}

.myClass {
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 8px;
  padding: 8px;
}

#overview { background-color: #fdd; }
#schedule { background-color: #dfd; }
#reports  { background-color: #ddf; }
```

```html
<div id="panel">
  <button class="myButtons" data="#overview">Only overview</button>
  <button class="myButtons" data="#schedule">Only schedule</button>
  <button class="myButtons" data="#reports">Only reports</button>
</div>
<div class="myClass" id="overview">Overview</div>
<div class="myClass" id="schedule">Schedule</div>
<div class="myClass" id="reports">Reports</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Absolutely better I think. And in order to make it 100% perfect, use `elements.forEach(e=>e.style.display="none")` and `elements.forEach(e=>e.addEventListener("click", hideExceptThis))`

Comment: @Attersson Thanks for the suggestion, I've changed `.getElementsByClassName()` to `.querySelectorAll()` to be able to apply it.

Comment: @Attersson, using `.getElementsByClassName()`, it says `elements.forEach is not a function`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266313/using-foreach-on-an-array-from-getelementsbyclassname-results-in-typeerror-und/36908845

Comment: Makes little sense since it is an array (woops. HTMLCollection). perhaps `[].forEach.apply(e=>{e.style.display="none";}, elements)`

Comment: The above hide the "button" (clicked item) - i am trying to hide the following:   var overview = document.getElementById("overview"); 
var schedule = document.getElementById("schedule");
var reports = document.getElementById("reports");

Comment: the buttons are outside of the elements - think of a floating side panel - yeah I figured more html would help - :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really clean, but at least it saves some lines of code.

Pass `this` (the element that fires the function) to your function and set all elements to `display: none;`, but set the element that got clicked back to `display: block;`.

```js
var overview = document.getElementById("overview");
var schedule = document.getElementById("schedule");
var reports = document.getElementById("reports");

function hide(element) {
  overview.style.display = "none";
  schedule.style.display = "none";
  reports.style.display = "none";
  element.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="overview" style="width: 100px; height: 15px; background-color: green" onclick="hide(this)"></div>
<div id="schedule" style="width: 100px; height: 15px; background-color: yellow" onclick="hide(this)"></div>
<div id="reports" style="width: 100px; height: 15px; background-color: blue" onclick="hide(this)"></div>
```

Comment: Argh! All that inline styling and script!…

Comment: @TakitIsy Indeed. :p

Comment: @TakitIsy +1 for your answer, it's much better than mine. x)

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate! :)

Comment: @EdwardDoyle I think you didn't comment the right answer… ;) CodeF0x, sorry to have stolen you the "correct answer"!