# Javascript getting index of the DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

Can you help me with the method to find the id of the DOM button clicked

```
out=document.getElementsByClassName("mybutton")
HTMLCollection(2) [button.mybutton, button.mybutton]
0
:
button.mybutton
1
:
button.mybutton
length
:
2
__proto__
:
HTMLCollection
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: in the function that gets executed on click, you can pass an event argument and in the function code you may use event.target.id to get the id

Answer (score 1):

Add a click handler to the buttons with `buttonElement.addEventListener('click', clickHandlerFunction);`.

```js
function onMyButtonClick(clickEvent) {
  var button = clickEvent.target;
  console.log('ID of clicked button: ' + button.id);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.querySelectorAll('.mybutton').forEach(function (button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', onMyButtonClick);
  })
});
```

```html
<button id="button-1" class="mybutton" type="button">Button 1</button>
<button id="button-2" class="mybutton" type="button">Button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Select all buttons in document.
2. Use for or forEach to iterate over list of buttons and add event listener to Each of the buttons.
3. Use getAttribute() method to get specific attribute of element(for example "id").

html:

```
<button class="mybutton" id ="one">1</button>
<button class="mybutton" id="two">2</button>
<button class="mybutton" id="three">3</button>
```

javascript:

```
let myButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("mybutton");

for (let i = 0; i < myButtons.length; i++) {
  myButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.getAttribute("id"));
  });
}
```

We can also use forEach method but because document.getElementsByClassName returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), not an array, with ES6 [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) which builds arrays from array-like objects we can use forEach method to iterate over HTMLColection objects. more details in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24266313/using-foreach-on-an-array-from-getelementsbyclassname-results-in-typeerror-und/24266344)

```
[...myButtons].forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.getAttribute("id"));
  });
});
```

Or you can use document.querySelectorAll() that return [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) instead of document.getElementsByClassName().

```
let myButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".mybutton");

myButtons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.getAttribute("id"));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your buttons looks something like this,

```
<button type="button" id="save" class="button">Save</button>
<button type="button" id="cancel" class="button">Cancel</button>
```

You can listen for the click events on the button and get its id using `event.target.id`

```
function handleClick(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id);  // prints the id of the clicked button
}

document.querySelectorAll(".button").forEach(function(button) { 
  button.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
});
```

ES6 approach:

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");
Array.from(buttons, button => button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(button.id) // prints the id of the clicked button
}));
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use for loop, and then check attribute of that element:

```
<button onClick="buttonClick($event)" id="something1" class="mybutton"></button>
<button id="something2" class="mybutton"></button>
<button id="something3" class="mybutton"></button>

function buttonClick(event) {
 for(var i = 0; i < out.length; i++) {
  if (event.target.attribute[0] === out[i].attributes[0].value){ 
  do something}
 }
}
```

this is if you need to check something, but click function alone with event will check which button is clicked.

Comment: How would this find the ID of the clicked element?

Comment: it would log the id of that element

Comment: Sorry , I meant the Index of the Dom element clicked . is there a method please

Comment: @NemanjaG This would log the ID of _all of the buttons_. Not the clicked button.

Comment: @Turnip this will check ID of clicked element, just pass event on click and use event.target, check my answer

Comment: @TarunKhanna event.target can check clicked element, check the answer.