# dynamic multidimensional array in jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push

I'd like to create a dynamic multidimensional array in jQuery/JS. But I can't get it to work:

```
var abc; // tried abc = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  $('#' + i).children().each(function() {
    abc[i][] = $(this).val(); // tried with abc[i].push(), abc[i][n] = ...
  });
}
```

Expected result:

```
Array (2)
0 Array (1)
0 ["abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"] (6)
1 Array (1)
0 ["abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc", "abc"] (6)
```

Can someone give me I hint?

`ERROR: undefined is not an object` or `Unexpected token ']'`

Comment: `abc` is not defined.  `undefined[i]` should be identifiable as an issue.  Also `abc[i][]` is not how you create a new sub array.  It would be `abc[i] = somearray`

Comment: You need to initialize `abc` as an array, as you tried, and then also every element of this array as an array: `abc[i] = []`

Comment: @Taplar So abc[i] = [$(this).val()];?

Comment: Potentially yes.  That is syntatically correct.  Though you should use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`

Comment: More like `var abc=[]; for(i..) { abc[i]=[]; children.each { abc[i].push(this.value) } }`

Comment: @Taplar didn't work :/. Take a look at my expected result.

Comment: @freedomn-m personally that looks like a prime usage case for `map()` instead of `each()`

Comment: @Taplar yes, I also thought of .map to solve OPs code, but the question appears to be about generating multi-dimension arrays on the fly rather than generating a (mutli-dimension) array of children values - the code only to demonstrate the problem not as the problem to be solved.  So just keeping OPs code as close as possible.

Comment: @freedomn-m what's the solution with map?

Comment: @LucaKiebel btw thanks for your reply :)! This works absolutly fine. But is it better to use map for this?

Comment: *is it better to use map for this* - no, it's not "better".  You use what you're comfortable with.  .map can give you nice short code for oft-repeated functionality (eg generating an array of values as you have here) as it's just `.map(()=>this.value).toArray()` and you have your array (no initialising or push).  But it *is* "better" to fully understand the code you write, not just copy+paste from the internet - and if you *fully* understand creating an array and pushing values into it, then stick with that.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> create a dynamic multidimensional array in jQuery/JS

Create the base array, then each of the first dimensions initialise as a new array so the values can be pushed into the second dimension.

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  arr[i] = [];
  $('#div' + i).children().each(function() {
    arr[i].push(this.value);
  });
}
```

```js
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  arr[i] = [];
  $('#div' + i).children().each(function() {
    arr[i].push(this.value);
  });
}
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper' id="div0">
      <input type='text' value="abc1-1">
      <input type='text' value="abc1-2">
      <input type='text' value="abc1-3">
      <input type='text' value="abc1-4">
      <input type='text' value="abc1-5">
    </div>
    <div class='wrapper' id="div1">
      <input type='text' value="abc2-1">
      <input type='text' value="abc2-2">
      <input type='text' value="abc2-3">
      <input type='text' value="abc2-4">
      <input type='text' value="abc2-5">
    </div>
    <div class='wrapper' id="div2">
      <input type='text' value="abc3-1">
      <input type='text' value="abc3-2">
      <input type='text' value="abc3-3">
      <input type='text' value="abc3-4">
      <input type='text' value="abc3-5">
    </div>
```

> what's the solution with map

**Using jquery:**

You can use jquery `.map` rather than loop through .children.each

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  arr.push($('#div' + i + ">*").map((i,e)=>e.value).toArray());
}
```

```js
// start with an empty array
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  arr.push($('#div' + i + ">*").map((i,e)=>e.value).toArray());
}
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div0">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-5">
</div>
<div id="div1">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-5">
</div>
<div id="div2">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-5">
</div>
```

removing the brittle hardcoded for loop 0..3, you can add a class to each "wrapper" (or use `$("#0,#1,#2")` and each on the outer)

```
var arr = [];

$(".wrapper").each((i, e) =>
  arr.push($(e).find(">*").map((ii, ee) => ee.value).toArray())
);
```

```js
var arr = [];

$(".wrapper").each((i, e) =>
  arr.push($(e).find(">*").map((ii, ee) => ee.value).toArray())
);
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper' id="div0">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-5">
</div>
<div class='wrapper' id="div1">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-5">
</div>
<div class='wrapper' id="div2">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-5">
</div>
```

Extending this, it *looks like* you could use a nested map:

```
var arr = $(".wrapper").map((i, e) => $(e).find(">*").map((ii, ee) => ee.value).toArray()).toArray();
```

but, as you'll see from the snippet, this flattens the final array.

```js
var arr = $(".wrapper").map((i, e) => $(e).find(">*").map((ii, ee) => ee.value).toArray()).toArray();
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper' id="div0">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-5">
</div>
<div class='wrapper' id="div1">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-5">
</div>
<div class='wrapper' id="div2">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-5">
</div>
```

**Using vanilla javascript**

These days there's also an Array.prototype.map function ("these days" - it's been around a while...but not forever) which you can use.  Sticking with vanilla js to get the DOM elements as well (see below to use jquery and convert to an array) along with some [ES6 fancyness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24266344/2181514) to convert from the HTMLCollection to an array gives the one liner:

```
var arr = [...document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")].map((e)=>[...e.children].map((ee)=>ee.value))
console.log(arr);
```

This bit `[...document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")]` converts the HTMLCollection to an array so we can use js .map

```js
var arr = [...document.getElementsByClassName("wrapper")].map((e)=>[...e.children].map((ee)=>ee.value))
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div class='wrapper' id="div0">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-5">
</div>
<div class='wrapper' id="div1">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-5">
</div>
<div class='wrapper' id="div2">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-5">
</div>
```

Now this uses nested .map (js .map not jquery .map) and *does* return the expected multi-dimensional array.

**Using jquery selectors and javascript map**

Finally, combining the succinctness of jquery selectors (or maybe you already have them as jquery objects so don't want to reselect them, any reason is fine) with js .map to get the nested map in (slightly) shorter code than the vanilla version:

```
var arr = $(".wrapper").toArray().map(e=>$(">*",e).toArray().map(ee=>ee.value));
console.log(arr);
```

here: `$(selector).toArray()` returns an array of DOM elements, so we can use js .map.

```js
var arr = $(".wrapper").toArray().map(e=>$(">*",e).toArray().map(ee=>ee.value));
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper' id="div0">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc1-5">
</div>
<div class='wrapper' id="div1">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc2-5">
</div>
<div class='wrapper' id="div2">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-1">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-2">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-3">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-4">
  <input type='text' value="abc3-5">
</div>
```