# Hide selected elements from the DOM without JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does the following code look like in native JS?

```
$(".custom-popover").hide();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That question is kind of broad. There is the way jQuery internally does it, and then there is a the way you can do it with just native JavaScript, independent of how jQuery may do it:

```
[].slice.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('.custom-popover')).forEach(function (el) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    }
);
```

Since `document.querySelectorAll` returns a `nodelist` that cannot be used with `forEach`, you can convert it to an actual array by calling `slice` on the `nodelist`. After that, loop through everything found and update the `style` property.

---

This is an **alternative** that does not use `forEach`, although I prefer the above approach:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('.custom-popover');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: why do we need [].slice.call()?

Comment: @ParagBhayani, since I decided to use `forEach`, it has to be an actual array, `forEach` will not work on `nodelists` in every browser.

Comment: Would you show me some example or link where I can learn this

Comment: @ParagBhayani, here's a couple more links: [a SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433799/why-doesnt-nodelist-have-foreach), and of course, the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) for nodelist

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed.