# Why can't I use Array.forEach on a collection of Javascript elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm building an app with Babel/ES6. I want to disable all form elements for a view-only version of it, so I did this:

```
let form = document.getElementById('application-form')
let elements = form.elements
```

I expected to be able to do this, instead of using a regular old `for` loop (which did work):

```
elements.forEach((el) => {
    el.disabled = true
})
```

but I got `TypeError: elements.forEach is not a function`

The strange thing is if I `console.log(elements)` in the Chrome dev console it exactly like an array with a bunch of `input` objects. It doesn't display with the `Object` notation for objects, and all of the keys are integers. I'm thinking it's some sort of pseudo array, but I wouldn't even know how to find that out.

**EDIT**: short answer it's not an array it's an HTMLCollection. see [Why doesn't nodelist have forEach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433799/why-doesnt-nodelist-have-foreach)

### *UPDATE*

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27024188/2212678), `nodelist` now has the `forEach` method!

Comment: And the result of `console.log(typeof elements)`

Comment: Fancy solution: `[...elements].forEach`

Comment: `object`. but it looked like an array in the dev console. looks like it is actually a HTMLCollection

Comment: Always check the type...do not use `duck testing`(If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably is a duck)

Comment: @squint: Ah, yes indeed. (I knew there had to be one, half the reason I CW'd -- the other half being the link to my arrays answer...) And since you say *you* reopened it...sure enough, I was able to dupehammer it (I don't think I could have if it had been me reopening).

Comment: I don't think reopening prevents one from closing. I did that to you one time when my pedantry engine was in high gear. I didn't check to see if it was already reopened when I clicked, so it could be I was behind you. In any case, I agree that this is a decent CW candidate.

Comment: @squint: *"...when my pedantry engine was in high gear..."* ROFL! I'm sure I have **no** idea what that's like.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can. You just can't use it *like that*, because there is no `forEach` property on the [`HTMLFormControlsCollection`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#htmlformcontrolscollection-0) that [`form.elements`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-elements) gives you (which isn't an array).

Here's how you can use it anyway:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(form.elements, (element) => {
    // ...
});
```

Or on modern browsers you can make use of the fact that the underlying `HTMLCollection` is *iterable* even though it doesn't have `forEach`:

```
// `for-of`:
for (const element of elements) {
    // ...do something with `element`...
}

// Spreading into an array:
[...elements].forEach((element) => {
    // ...do something with `element`...
});
```

That won't work on obsolete browsers like IE11 though.

There's also `Array.from` (needs a polyfill for obsolete browsers):

```
Array.from(elements).forEach((element) => {
    // ...
});
```

For details, see the *"array-like"* part of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Comment: ES6 conversion: `[...elements].forEach(el => el.disabled = true);`

Comment: @SterlingArcher: Indeed! Hmmm, I'm not sure my answer linked above mentions that... Edit: Ah, yes, it does. But it incorrectly calls it an operator. Edit2: Not any more. :-)

Comment: Feel free to edit into solution, since ES6 is indeed tagged. `Array.from` is also good.

Comment: Using the `spread` is an awesome trick.

Comment: @inostia: Yeah, so succinct!

Comment: @SterlingArcher: That and the `.from()` solution are fine, but they unnecessarily create a new Array and copies in the nodes. Too bad Firefox's Array generic methods weren't standardized. Nicer to do `Array.forEach(elements, function(el) {...})`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder actually that did not work for me. `[...elements].forEach` gave me an Unexpected Token error with WebPack. But `let elements = [...form.elements]; elements.forEach` did work.

Comment: @squint: Indeed. It's really well optimized, but still...

Comment: @inostia: !!! Good catch, spread will only work with iterables! Not everything that `Array.from` can turn into an array is an iterable! Interestingly, the result of `querySelectorAll` appears to be iterable (on Chrome) and works fine with spread notation.

Comment: @SterlingArcher: See inostia's note above, which I can verify. Oops!

Comment: Are you sure? `[...document.querySelectorAll("div")].forEach(x => console.log(x));` runs in my console just fine. Unless HTMLCollection != NodeList?

Comment: @SterlingArcher: I can verify that not all array-like objects work with spread notation: https://jsfiddle.net/3p0jntco/ (of course, if we think about it). For me on Chrome, QSA's return value and `HTMLFormControlsCollection` both work with spread notation, but apparently webpack thinks not, which makes me wonder if there are implementations in the wild that also think not... Basically, they'd have to be iterable. It makes *sense* for them to be iterable, but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder like I mentioned, using the `forEach` directly on `[...elements]` failed, but I was able to set `[...form.elements]` to a variable and iterate over that with `forEach`. Maybe a webpack issue

Comment: @inostia: Sorry, misread that, of course you did say. But do note that you're relying on iterability there. Need to check the relevant specs to make sure that's guaranteed (well, you'll test in your target browsers anyway, and transpiling will do an `Array.from`-like thing anyway).

Comment: Just to add an alternative, if you can use ES6, just go with `for (var el of elements) {}`.

Comment: @Marc: On modern browsers only, yeah; these DOM collections only recently became iterable. So if you're transpiling for older browsers (like IE11), that won't work.

Answer (score 4):

You **cannot** use `forEach` on `HMTLCollection`. `forEach` can only be used on `array.

Alternatives are, use [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) and do `_.toArray()`, which will convert the HTMLColelction to an array. After this, you can do normal array operations over it. Or, use ES6 `spread` and do `forEach()`

Like this,

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
[...a].forEach()
```

Answer (score 0):

`form.elements`, `document.getElementsByTagName`, `document.getElementsByClassName` and `document.querySelectorAll` return a node list.

A node list is essentially an object that doesn't have any methods like an array.

If you wish to use the node list as an array you can use `Array.from(NodeList)` or the oldschool way of `Array.prototype.slice.call(NodeList)`

```js
// es6
const thingsNodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.thing')
const thingsArray = Array.from(thingsNodeList)
thingsArray.forEach(thing => console.log(thing.innerHTML))

// es5
var oldThingsNodeList = document.getElementsByClassName('thing')
var oldThingsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(oldThingsNodeList)
thingsArray.forEach(function(thing){ 
  console.log(thing.innerHTML) 
})
```

```html
<div class="thing">one</div>
<div class="thing">two</div>
<div class="thing">three</div>
<div class="thing">four</div>
```