# Access elements inside element with ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<div ref={location} className={style.locations}>
        {locations.map(loc => (
          <span onClick={onClick}>
            {loc.name}
          </span>
        ))}
</div>
```

I want to access the `<span>` inside the `<div>` with "location" ref:

```
const span = location.current.getElementsByTagName("span");
span.forEach(el => {
   el.style.display = "none";
})
```

But I just get error:

```
span.forEach is not a function
```

Comment: which errors do you get?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I use Array.forEach on a collection of Javascript elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797101/why-cant-i-use-array-foreach-on-a-collection-of-javascript-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[...span].forEach(el => {
   el.style.display = "none";
})
```