# How to retrieve a dynamic number of elements by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if there is a better way to make these hand coded function calls  dynamic?

```
<div id="sing-mobile-1">.....</div>
<div id="sing-mobile-2">.....</div>
```

```js
var signCarousel1 = document.getElementById("sing-mobile-1");
var signCarousel2 = document.getElementById("sing-mobile-2");

if (signCarousel1) {
  var initializeSignpostCarousel = sequence(signCarousel1, options);
}
if (signCarousel2) {
  var initializeSignpostCarousel = sequence(signCarousel2, options);
}
```

There may also be `#sign-mobile-3`, `#sign-mobile-4`, etc. It doesn't look clean in this way. Can someone guide me to solve this issue?

Comment: Give those element common class name, then it'll be easier to iterate through them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting an indeterminate number of elements by their `id`, use a single class on them all. You can then loop through all the elements with that class and call your function:

```
<div class="sing-mobile">...</div>
<div class="sing-mobile">...</div>
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.sing-mobile').forEach(function(el) {
  var initializeSignpostCarousel = sequence(el, options);
  // work with initializeSignpostCarousel here...
});
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$('.sing-mobile').each(function() {
  var initializeSignpostCarousel = sequence(this, options);
  // work with initializeSignpostCarousel here...
});
```

Comment: `NodeList.prototype.forEach` is a rather new addition to NodeLists. It's not supported (yet) in Internet Explorer and Edge at all. But NodeLists can be converted to arrays using `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList)`.

Comment: @AndreasLinnert Looks like it should work fine for IE8 and IE9 going by the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: @MasterYoda Andreas is talking about [nodeList.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), and is correct. It's a good point, and there are [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433799/why-doesnt-nodelist-have-foreach) - I just yearn for a time we aren't held back by IE :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Fair enough, apologies for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - This solution works to show the slider element. But, slider auto sliding not working as expected.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'auto sliding'. Is that logic in your `sequence()` method? I'd suggest starting a new question about it, including the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use wildcard `^` to do this

```
function getElem() {

  // ^ is a wildcard which will pick all elements whose id starts with sing-mobile-1
  $el = $("[id^=sing-mobile-]");
  if ($el.length == 0)
    return false;


  var initializeSignpostCarousel = sequence($el[0], options);
  return initializeSignpostCarousel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=sing-mobile-]');

for (let elem of elements) {
    var initializeSignpostCarousel = sequence(elem, options);
}
```