# Why can I forEach through some NodeList's but not all?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html

As I've answered questions on this website, I've began to use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) a lot more. I've also started using [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), or [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) a lot more.

I've recently noticed that sometimes, `.forEach()` works, and sometimes it doesn't. After a bit of research, I found out that you can't `.forEach()` through a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Then I went to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27024188/10768127) and found out that you can `.forEach()` on a NodeList.

**Note:** I've also added 2 snippets below in which `.forEach()` works, and doesn't work. It seems to work for `document.querySelectorAll()` but not `document.getElementsByClassName()`, but why? Don't they both return a `NodeList`?

### **TL;DR:** Why can I `.forEach()` on some `NodeLists`, but not all?

`.forEach()` works on this snippet.

```js
let text = document.querySelectorAll(".text");

console.log(typeof text);
text.forEach(e => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<div class="text">Text</div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
```

`.forEach()` doesn't work on this snippet.

```js
let text = document.getElementsByClassName("text");

console.log(typeof text);
text.forEach(e => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<div class="text">Text</div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, but `getElementsByClassName` returns a `HTMLCollection`:

```js
let querySelector = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
let className = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
console.log(querySelector.constructor.name);
console.log(className.constructor.name);
```

```html
<div class="text">Text</div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
```

You have to convert a `HTMLCollection` to an array before you can iterate over it:

```js
let text = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("text"));

text.forEach(e => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

```html
<div class="text">Text</div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
<div class="text">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `getElementsByClassName` doesn't returns an array but a `HTMLCollection`. It's an `array-like` object, as described on the documentation.

If you want to iterate over a `HTMLCollection` **without having to convert anything**, you could use:

```
const list = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
const matches = Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, (el) => console.log(el));
```

I've added a snippet to clarify this works fine:

```js
const list = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
const matches = Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, (el) => console.log(el));
```

```html
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
  <div class="text"></div>
```

References:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 1):

**`getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection`** which doesn't have a `forEach` method.

```js
let text1 = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
let text2 = document.getElementsByClassName("text");

console.log(text1.forEach);
console.log(text2.forEach);
```

```html
<div class="text">Text</div>
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName