# Uncaught TypeError: forEach is not a function error in javascript function

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I have this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: trList.forEach is not a function
```

in this function

```
function findMatchingRow(word) {
   const found = []
   const trList = document.querySelectorAll('#main_table_countries_today > tbody > tr')
   trList.forEach(function(tr, i) {
       if(tr.textContent.match(word)) {
           found.push({index: i, content: tr.textContent})
       }
       })
       return found
   }

{const matches = findMatchingRow('Tunisia')
 console.log(matches)
 if(matches.length > 0) {
     console.log('found at:', matches.map(function(m) { return m.index; }))}}
```

This problem related to ES6 compatiblity i think

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433799/why-doesnt-nodelist-have-foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Use a `for` loop like this:
`for (var i = 0; i < trList.length; i++) { ... }`
and inside of it replace `tr` with `trList[i]`
You might need to remove one `)` that was ending the opening parenthesis of the `forEach` loop you just replaced.

*Original answer*:

*Try changing the fourth line in your code with this:*
*`Array.prototype.forEach.call(trList, function (tr, i) {`*

Comment: i got as an output -1 instead of 89 that i got from webview in android 8 and 9
in android 5.1 `[INFO:CONSOLE(15)] "found at:", source:  (15)
D: -1`  in android 8 and 9  `INFO:CONSOLE(15)] "found at: 88", source:  (15)
D: 89`

Comment: Then I guess you need to use a simple for like `for (var i = 1; i <= trList.length; i++)`

Comment: With for loop, i got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' `, so i deleted the ) and i got `Uncaught ReferenceError: tr is not defined`

Comment: Yes, if you use a simple `for` loop you won't need an extra `)` at the end. You will need to replace all your `tr`'s with `trList[i]`. I'll edit my answer since it didn't work

Comment: Right, I was starting the for in 1, not in 0, I edited my answer, see if it works now

Comment: it worked, but i still get -1 instead of 89 from `console.log` in the end, and i think it's an es6 compatibilty issue, android 5.1 use es5 i think, do you have solution for that ?

Comment: here is the two errors i got `I: [INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "TypeError: Cannot set property style of #<Element> which has only a getter", source: https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_2020030501.js (6)
`  `I: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "TypeError: e.includes is not a function", source: https://c.amazon-adsystem.com/aax2/apstag.js (2)
`

Comment: I believe those errors are not located in the code of your original question. Probably there are lots of code that you are using or importing in your system that won't run in old versions of Android :(

Comment: i updated the webview and it worked, but, it still not a solution, appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

QuerySelectorAll returns a nodeList which is not a true JS Array. You have to convert that into a true JS Array that has all the Array methods.

I created a utility function that does this for me.

```
 function nodeListToArray(elem){
    return [].slice().call(elem);
 }
```

Then you use it like this.

```
const trList = document.querySelectorAll('#main_table_countries_today > tbody > tr');
const trArr = nodeListToArray(trList);
```

The “trArr” will have the forEach method.

Comment: I'm a beginner in js, this will be hard for me to do it, can you help with codes ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i got `Uncaught TypeError: [].slice(...).call is not a function
`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const trList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#main_table_countries_today > tbody > tr'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'm getting this error now Uncaught TypeError: Array.from is not a function

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a `nodeList`. Convert it to an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
const trList = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#main_table_countries_today > tbody > tr'))'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'm getting this error now `Uncaught TypeError: Array.from is not a function`

Comment: @JDEVss what browser are you using? current compatibility > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Comment: i'm using android 5.1 webview, the code works for android 8 and 9 but not android 5.1

Comment: you can iterate over it with a basic for loop. do; `for(let i =0; i < trList.length;i++){...}`

Comment: @JDEVss Update your device and your original code should work. Lollipop devices can use the latest version of WebView.

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina With for loop, i got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'` , so i deleted the )  and i got `Uncaught ReferenceError: tr is not defined
`

Comment: you have to define`tr` which will look like `let tr = trList[i]` (when inside of the loop)